# Create a DataTable using code and add it to a DataGridView c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have fetched tables with their related tables and added them to a simple custom `DataTable`. Then, using this `DataTable` as the data source of the `DataGridView`. Code runs fine and my `DataTable` has rows. However, the `GridView` is blank and isn't showing anything. Below is my code within a static method:

```
DataTable optionDt = new DataTable("Options");
DataColumn optionName = new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string));
DataColumn optionVal = new DataColumn("Value", typeof(string));
optionDt.Columns.Add(optionName);
optionDt.Columns.Add(optionVal);
if (frmMode == FormUtilities.MODEADD)
{
    if (PRODUCT_VARIATION.ProdOptions.Count() > 0)
    {
        flOptionPanel.Controls.Clear();
        optionSkus.Clear();
        foreach (ProductOption po in PRODUCT_VARIATION.ProdOptions)
        {
            if (optionSkus.Count() < 3)
            {
                optionSkus.Add(po.Value);
            }

            if (optionDt != null)
            {

                optionDt.Rows.Add(po.Name, po.Value);

            }                        
        }
        staticDataGVSpecification.DataSource = optionDt;
    } 
}
```

Comment: When you say the grid view is blank, do you mean no rows and no columns are shown or rows are added, but no data is shown in the columns?

Comment: Hi, there is no row n no columns showing in the DataGridView but there is data in the DataTable.

Comment: Did you set the DGV controls AutoGenerateColumns to false?

Comment: Yes i tried setting them to FILL, All CELL, NONE, nothings worked

Comment: It was a silly mistake of initializing the static DataGridView variable. M sorry about the trouble, i definately need a break :P